# Java split regular expression

Tags: java, regex

If I have a string, e.g.

```
setting=value
```

How can I remove the '=' and turn that into two separate strings containing 'setting' and 'value' respectively?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two options spring to mind.

The first `split()`s the `String` on `=`:

```
String[] pieces = s.split("=", 2);
String name = pieces[0];
String value = pieces.length > 1 ? pieces[1] : null;
```

The second uses regexes directly to parse the `String`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)=(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
  String name = m.group(1);
  String value = m.group(2);      
}
```

The second gives you more power. For example you can automatically lose white space if you change the pattern to:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(.*?)\\s*=\\s*(.*)\\s*");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression for this, just do:

```
String str = "setting=value";
String[] split = str.split("=");
// str[0] == "setting", str[1] == "value"
```

You might want to set a `limit` if `value` can have an `=` in it too; see the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split)

Comment: That _is_ using regular expression, though. For example, if you want to split on `?`, you can't just `str.split("?")`. You'd have to escape it to `str.split("\\?")`.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot Java's String.split takes a regular expression; most languages split on a string